# TabLayout with ViewPager is not selected programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have `Tabs` set with `ViewPager`. If I select tabs in app or by swiping page it will trigger `onTabSelected()` but if I select first tab programatically, it will not trigger this function. I need to set it programmatically because I want to set button visibility by tab position (some buttons are not visible if first tab is selected).

```
pagerAdapter = CustomViewPagerAdapter(pageList)
viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager){
   override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
   override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
   override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
      App.log("btnVisibility: onSelected")
      setButtonsVisibility()
   }
})

viewPager.currentItem = 0
//TRIED THIS ONE TOO - NOT WORKING
tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()
```

UPDATE:

Found solution: `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)` has to be called after all tab/page changes. If you call it before `viewPager.currentItem = 0` or `tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()` these rows will not work with your current `tabLayout` or `viewPager`. Pretty weird. I thought that it is just used to connect your `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` not that actual state is saved permanently and you cant do changes to `ViewPager` later.

Comment: Try `TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`

Comment: tried already, doesnt work

Comment: Try with `if (tab.position == 0){ setVisibility }` in to `onTabSelected()`

Comment: still doesnt work. Ive added log there and it is not called at all during init process. Only if i click on tab or swipe page

Comment: Try to remove `viewPager.currentItem = 0` and `tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.select()` and then check it